# How do I make a "proxy" class for a web service in Eclipse for Java?

Tags: c#, java, visual-studio, web-services, eclipse

I can't figure this out, I'm a pretty novis Eclipse user. I'm a .NET/C# Guy by trade, and playing with Java in my spare time.

I have a .NET WCF Service hosted with basicHttpBinding -- I'm successfully calling this service from another .NET application, I've used the Visual Studio SvcUtil to generate the proxy class (via Add Service Reference).

I'm wondering how I can achieve the same result for Java using Eclipse? I've downloaded the latest version of Eclipse, but I can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look under File -> New -> Other.  In the dialog, select Web Service Client.

If you don't see this option, you're probably missing the [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) plugin.

There's a tutorial [here](http://px.pats.no/px/Eclipse_tutorial.html), that steps you through the process (though on an older version of eclipse).

Comment: the tutorials is down